# How to execute some code after some specific HTTP verbs were executed

Tags: reactjs, axios

I need to execute some code after every PUT, PATCH and POST. I don't want in every axios call to execute my code after I get the response; I want the code to be declared in one place to make sure its execution is triggered for every PUT/POST/PATCH. I thought of axios reponse interceptors but you get to do something before your return the reponse while as in my case, I want the response forst to be returned, then I will execute my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checkout for [axios middleware](https://emileber.github.io/axios-middleware/#/)

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { Service } from 'axios-middleware';

const service = new Service(axios);

service.register({
  onRequest(config) {
    console.log('onRequest');
    //EDIT YOUR REQUEST CONFIG
    return config;
  },
  onResponse(response) {
    console.log('onResponse');
    //EDIT YOUR RESPONSE
    return response;
  }
});

axios('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
  .then(({ data }) => console.log('Received:', data));
```